# Ubuntu 15.10 - HDMI connection to Samsung HDTV no longer working

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, hdtv

I use a HP Pavilion dv5 laptop. I have been connecting it to a Samsung HDTV for over 6 months now via a HDMI outlet and everything worked seamlessly. I was new to Ubuntu then, and surprised that it was so simple. It was literally plug and play: the TV was immediately recognised by the OS as a second monitor and I could drag windows between the two without issue. Audio worked without issue as well.

This pattern of use was consistent, without fail, until today when I went to use my laptop at 7pm. The TV reads 'no signal'.

I've tried both ports on the TV and tried a different HDMI cable but there's just no recognition of the TV's existence within the GUI of the OS. In places where it used to be, like 'Screen Display' and 'Sound'

Funny thing is it worked only earlier today, at about 2pm. The only thing that has happened since then is I shut down the laptop and went grocery shopping...

This person is also having a similar problem but with 14.04, from two days ago:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/726422/ubuntu-14-04-hdmi-cable-not-registering

I wanted to comment with my issue on this question, but I don't yet have enough 'reputation'.
I'm having no luck finding grammar or spelling issues in questions; which is a recommended way of gaining reputation. I don't know enough about the inner workings of GNU/Linux to answer any real questions... 
The only thing I know how to do is hide folders with a '.' in front of the filename: but someone had already provided that answer so no dice.
(I'm getting off topic here though....)

It could be a faulty update that's caused this to happen, so is there a way to roll back updates?

Comment: Funny, I had similar issue a few days ago. But I applied "computer fixing method number 1" (turn off, turn on)  and it went back to normal operation. Note: to be sure your TV is completely turned off (and not just suspended) unplug it from the power outlet for a few seconds.